# Tag stack created by Codepipeline

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

Is it possible to add tags to stacks created by Codepipeline using Cloudformation as the Provider for Deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-cfn-artifacts.html) says you have a possibility to set tags for your stack in Template Configuration File. Note that end of the article illustrate an example where Configuration File has an `Tags` section with `"Department" : "Marketing"` key-value.

Comment: Thanks! Using a combination of ParameterOverrides and TemplateConfiguration File worked.

Comment: @NamitaModak Would you be kind enough to share an example of the same?